# Saving QML's ChartView to image file in PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qml, qtcharts

My approach was pretty much as such:

Chart.qml:

```
Window {
    ChartView {
        id: chartView
        // ...
    }

    Button {
        text: "save"
        onClicked: manager.save(chartView)
    }
}
```

Manager.py:

```
class Manager(QObject):
    @pyqtSlot(QObject)
    def save(self, chartview):
        img = chartview.grab()
        img.save(MY_DEFAULT_PATH)
```

The problem is, of course, that inside the `Manager.save()` the chartview is equivalent of C++'s `QObject*` which does not have the 'grab' method. But it could be downcasted to `QChartView*` (or at least `QWidget*`) which, such method, has. In C++ I would do it probably with qobject_cast.

My questions are:

1. Is such downcasting doable in PyQt?
2. If not - do you have any idea how could it be done differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before giving the answer it is better to clarify some errors that the post has:

- The QML ChartView is an Item unlike the QChartView which is a QWidget. And that Item is painted using the information from a QGraphicsScene and QChart. Considering the above, one method could be to access the QGraphicsScene and QChart, and use the `render()` method of QGraphicsScene.
- You can do casting using sip through the `sip.cast()` method.
- In this case, it is not necessary to do a downcasting either, since it is enough to indicate in the signature to:

```
class Manager(QtCore.QObject):
    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtQuick.QQuickItem)
    def save(self, chartview):
        self.result = chartview.grabToImage()

        def handle_ready():
            self.result.saveToFile(MY_DEFAULT_PATH)
            delattr(self, "result")

        self.result.ready.connect(handle_ready)
```

But instead of getting too complicated you can use the grabToImage method since it is an Item:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12
import QtCharts 2.2

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    Button {
        id: btn
        text: "Save"
        anchors.top: parent.top
        onClicked: saveChart("chart.png") 
    }
    ChartView {
        id: chartView
        anchors.top: btn.bottom
        width: parent.width
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        LineSeries {
            XYPoint { x: 0; y: 0 }
            XYPoint { x: 1.1; y: 2.1 }
        }
    }

    function saveChart(filename){
        chartView.grabToImage(function(result) {
            result.saveToFile(filename);
        });
    }   
}
```